# FIND previous businessday this code is too slow

Tags: sql-server

My code to find prior business day (only date, without time part) takes 1 minute to execute which is too long. Please help to find an alternative. It is a stored procedure which takes value from diff tables in which I take currentdate to get previous day data (exclude weekends).

Code:

```
convert(varchar(10), utilization_date, 111) = dateadd(day, 
                        CASE WHEN datepart(day, getdate()) = 1 THEN -2 
                             WHEN datepart(day, getdate()) = 2 THEN -3 
                             ELSE -1
                        END, 
                        convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 111))
```

Comment: If you convert dates to strings, you prevent your query from using any indexes. Why do you use `convert(varchar(10),Utilization_Date,111)` instead of just `Utilication_Date`? What could be a simple index seek, is turned into a full table scan this way

Comment: i don't think that logic will give you previous business day

Comment: The code you posted is not likely the part of the query that is taking a long time. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms174420.aspx for DatePart documentation, you probably want to use "DatePart(dw, getdate())". As noted above, you can't assign a value to "convert(varchar(10), utilization_date, 111) = ".

Comment: this entire code comes in 'where ' part of a big sp,..using this code take moretime to execute the entire sp... is there any other solution